# Spark Job not getting any cores on EC2

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, pyspark

I use `flintrock 0.9.0` with `spark 2.2.0` to start my cluster on EC2. the code is written in `pyspark` I have been doing this for a while now and run a couple of successful jobs. In the last 2 days I encountered a problem that when I start a cluster on certain instances I don't get any cores. I observed this behavior on `c1.medium` and now on `r3.xlarge` the code to get the `spark` and `spark context` `objects` is this

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('the_final_join')\
                  .setMaster(master)\
                  .set('spark.executor.memory','29G')\
                  .set('spark.driver.memory','29G')

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf) 
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```

on `c1.medium` is used `.set('spark.executor.cores', '2')` and it seemed to work. But now I tried to run my code on a bigger cluster of `r3.xlarge` instances and my Job doesn't get any code no matter what I do. All workers are alive and I see that each of them should have 4 cores. Did something change in the last 2 months or am I missing something in the startup process? I launch the instances in `us-east-1c` I don't know if this has something to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your issue may be that your are trying to allocate more memory to the Driver/Executors than you have access to.

> yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb controls the maximum sum of memory used by the containers on each node ([cite](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/))

You can look up this value for various instances [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-task-config.html). r3.xlarge have access to 23,424M, but your trying to give your driver/executor 29G. Yarn is not launching Spark, ultimately, because it doesn't have access to enough memory to run your job.

Comment: I'm neither using EMR nor YARN to run the cluster and at least on paper r3.xlarge should have 30.5 GiB. of memory and Sparks webUI tells me that there are 29 GiB of available memory per worker. I reduced it to 27GiB and it seems to be doing the trick. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Ah, poor reading comprehension on my part. Glad it help anyways and that you resolved the issue